# Execute Select with more than one column and assign to Labels

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms

I am working on a way to be able to run a SELECT Statement that returns more than one value into two different labels on my application.

The idea is to be able to get some version information from the database by running a select on the DB picked, I got the code to work but I know it's super sloppy and im just not really sure how to clean it up. I know there has to be a better way than what I have going on here.

```
// Update Version & Version2         
        string sqlCom1 = String.Format(@"SELECT [Version] 
                                            FROM ConfigSystem");
        string sqlCom = String.Format(@"SELECT Version2 
                                            FROM ConfigSystem");

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnectionString.DataSource = "SQL06";
        ConnectionString.InitialCatalog = "SuperSweetDB";
        ConnectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        SqlConnection cnn;
        cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString());


        using (var version = new SqlCommand(sqlCom1, cnn))
        {
             cnn.Open();
             label.Text = (string)version.ExecuteScalar();
             cnn.Close();
        };
        using (var version = new SqlCommand(sqlCom, cnn))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            label2.Text = (string)version.ExecuteScalar();
        };
```

I *think*, and I'm not certain, that I am opening to connections to get data that I could easily get in SQL with one. The issue that it returns to columns worth of data and I have not been able to find it in Google on how to handle this. (I'm probably looking for the wrong thing)

I only did it this way because I really needed it to work, now I'm trying to clean everything up.

Just a heads up, Fairly new to C# or anything that is not SQL.

Any help is appreciated, if this is a duplicate question I apologize.

Comment: Have a look at this -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877584/multiple-sql-queries-asp-net-c-sharp and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

Comment: This looks promising thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that I came up with in case anyone needs help on this in the future:

```
string sqlCom = String.Format(@"SELECT [Version],version2 FROM ConfigSystem");
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnectionString.DataSource = SQL06;
        ConnectionString.InitialCatalog = "SuperSweetdb";
        ConnectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString());

        using (var version = new SqlCommand(sqlCom, cnn))
        {           
            cnn.Open();

            using(IDataReader dataReader = version.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    label7.Text = dataReader["Version"].ToString();
                    label9.Text = dataReader["VertexDataVersion"].ToString();
                }
            }

        };
```

What I ended up doing was breaking it down with datareader. This was kind of difficult to figure out and required a lot of tinkering but in the end it's a cleaner connection that prior to what I had.

Basically DataReader is what I was looking for.

Here is a link to something that helped out quite e bit: [Invalid attempt to read when no data is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147615/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present)

As well as this: [Multiple SQL queries asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877584/multiple-sql-queries-asp-net-c-sharp)

Hopefully anyone who has a similar problem will be able to get some help from this.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your 2 SQL statements with a semi-colon in 1 string variable, and then use the NextResult() method on the SqlDataReader to get multiple resultsets back.

I updated your code to work. See below. Notice the use of using keyword automatically disposes off the resources after code execution. I tested the code using SQL Server built in variables in 2 sql statements, which are commented.

You should be able to paste the following code in a console app and run it successfully.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SqlMultipleResultsets
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        ConnectionString.DataSource = "SQL06";
        ConnectionString.InitialCatalog = "SuperSweetDB";

        //ConnectionString.DataSource = "(localdb)\\Projects";
        //ConnectionString.InitialCatalog = "tempdb";

        ConnectionString.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        string sqlSelect = @"SELECT [Version] FROM ConfigSystem;" +
                            @"SELECT Version2 FROM ConfigSystem";

        // string sqlSelect = @"SELECT [Version] = @@VERSION;"
        //                    + @"SELECT Version2 = @@LANGUAGE;" ;

            int recordCount;

            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, cnn))
                {
                    cnn.Open( );
                    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader( );

                    recordCount = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Result set: {0}", ++recordCount);
                        while (dr.Read( ))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", dr[0]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    } 
                    while (dr.NextResult( ));                    
                }   // END command
            }   // END connection
            Console.Write("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        } // END Main
    }
}
```

Comment: This was probably the closest answer, however the only difference, and this is probably my fault, is that I was looking to make 1 select instead of two. I should have clarified, but your answer did help me out a bit. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MitchellHamann Glad it helped. If you are looking for 1 SELECT instead of two, here's 1 way of doing it. Change sqlSelect string to be as follows.

        string sqlSelect = @"SELECT Title='Version', Value= [Version] FROM ConfigSystem" +
                           @" UNION " +
                           @"SELECT Title='Version2', Value = Version2 FROM ConfigSystem";


This will give you 2 rows, with 2 columns, 1st column containing the word "Version" and "Version2" respectively, and 2nd column containing the actual values. Hope this helps! --Shiva

Answer (score 0):

You could create the SqlCommand only once and reuse it - you can set the command dynamically:

```
using (var version = new SqlCommand())
{
    version.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    version.Connection = cnn;

    cnn.Open();
    version.CommandText = sqlCom1;
    label.Text = (string)version.ExecuteScalar();

    version.CommandText = sqlCom2;
    label2.Text = (string)version.ExecuteScalar();
    cnn.Close();
};
```

There are a lot of examples in the official [SqlCommand class documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx).