# Multiple Selects In Query Not Giving All Result Sets

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my code there is a loop that gives the results of an SQL query using SqlCommand.
However, for some queries that I need to run there are multiple select statements in the query. For example, this might be what the entire statement would look like:

```
Dim query as string = "
    Select * from people
    Select * from places
    Select * from items
    Select * from foods"

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, connect)
cmd.Connection.Open()
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

While reader.HasRows()
//various logic
While reader.Read()
//Do Logic Here
End While
End While
```

When my query is ran I get the results for the first 2 but since the 3rd one has no results it kicks the application out of the loop and I do not get the results of the 4th select. I need the results of the 4th select also.

Edit: Union will not work for this case because I need to be able to differentiate between result sets in my logic.

Comment: Have you tried `UNION ALL` between each query?

Comment: Union will not work, I need to be able to differentiate between result sets.

Comment: use `reader.NextResult` in an outer loop

Comment: Or instead of a reader, populate a DataSet and iterate through the Tables collection.

Comment: As per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5877616/5233918), a good approach might be to run separate queries on the same connection.

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin The application is designed to have a SQL file passed into it and then use that file. So, not a static number of selects.

Comment: @BryantFrankford Can't you split the string on newlines and loop over each `SELECT`?

Comment: @MichaelMcMullin maybe my example query is poor, the real queries end up being hundreds of lines long, with multiple result sets

Comment: From the way I'm reading this, he wants to manipulate the data from each result set individually using logic in VB, but in order to avoid hitting an exception he is using while reader.HasRows so that calling while reader.read does not error out. None of the suggestions above will work for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("zp_multiple_results", connect);
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        do
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
                }
        }
        while (reader.NextResult());

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```